# ORACLE Connect by clause equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, hierarchical-data

Is there a equivalent clause to CONNECT BY of Oracle in SQL Server. The requirement to build a category tree using a parentId field.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SQL Server 2005+ equivalent of Oracle's `CONNECT BY` hierarchical query syntax is to use a recursive CTE.  SQL Server 2008 added [HierarchyID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794278.aspx).  Here's an example of a recursive CTE:

```
WITH EmployeeHierarchy (EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, ReportsTo, HierarchyLevel) AS (
   SELECT EmployeeID,
          LastName,
          FirstName,
          ReportsTo,
          1 as HierarchyLevel
     FROM Employees
    WHERE ReportsTo IS NULL
   UNION ALL
   -- Recursive step
   SELECT e.EmployeeID,
          e.LastName,
          e.FirstName,
          e.ReportsTo,
          eh.HierarchyLevel + 1 AS HierarchyLevel
     FROM Employees e
     JOIN EmployeeHierarchy eh ON e.ReportsTo = eh.EmployeeID)
  SELECT *
    FROM EmployeeHierarchy
ORDER BY HierarchyLevel, LastName, FirstName
```

Googling "hierarchical CTE" and/or "recursive CTE" will turn up numerous results.  I took the example query from the [4GuysFromRolla.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927200924/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml).

Recursive CTEs are now ANSI standard - the syntax wasn't supported until Oracle 11g as I understand.

Answer (score 1):

There's [HierarchyID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794278.aspx) data type in MS SQL Server 2008, which can make your life easier.