# MySql: order record by id and parent

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `Table1` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`parent` INT NOT NULL,
`comment` TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);
```

Which has following sample data (with some user generated text in comment field)

```
+------+---------+-
| id   | parent  |
+------+---------+
| 1    |    0    |
| 2    |    1    |
| 3    |    0    |
| 4    |    1    |
| 5    |    0    |
| 6    |    5    |
| 7    |    4    |
+------+---------+
```

How can I get following order in SELECT statement.

```
+------+---------+-
| id   | parent  |
+------+---------+
| 1    |    0    |
| 2    |    1    |
| 4    |    1    |
| 7    |    4    |
| 3    |    0    |
| 5    |    0    |
| 6    |    5    |
+------+---------+
```

I want to list a record after its parent record, and rows with parent 0 should be sorted on basis of their 'id'.

Comment: Not clear could you explain a bit more about the sorting logic you are after ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want rows with parent 0 on top, and then sorted by id, like the rest of your rows? I can't see how this ordering could be useful. If you apply a different sorting rule depending on the value... then it is not really sorted

Comment: MySQL is not designed to do these kind of things, better to do this after you have extracted the data by looping through the array.

Comment: I agree with the previous commenters. The SQL sort order logic would expect there is an explicit value by which the results should be ordered. In the latter `select` there is nothing like that. And btw, I think the table structure is also kind of risky or unclear; if the `parent` value can't be null and it points to the same table, what is the parent value of the first inserted row? (I know there's no referential integrity defined but that `0` parent reference might cause you trouble later when there is no row with that id.)

Comment: @ AbhikChakraborty I want to sort the comments posted by site users based on under which comment they have posted it.

@Toaster I am sure "I do not want all rows with parent 0 together and and on the begining".
 
@ Jester I am not sure if you are correct. I am just looking for solutions.

@ MJV a record can have parent as 0, if it has no parent.

Comment: @pin, did you insist id's with parent 0 to be 0, but not null?

Comment: @mitkosoft nope. Logically for me it is ok if parent in 0 or null.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly, your comments are structured as a tree (root is 0, others all have a parent and are ultimately linked to 0).
I don't know which sql tech you use, but Oracle provides a way to display the tree elements in order.

Look for "start with" and "connect by", for example here:
http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/connect_by.html

I think this could help you achieve what you want to do

Something like (not tested at all, just a hint)

```
select * from Table1 start with 0 connect by parent
```

**EDIT**

Since You actually use MySQL, the above solution is not possible (Thanks @MJV for noticing).
Here is an idea of a solution. It assumes that you can add more info in your table when inserting a new comment. It also assume that a new comment will have a higher ID than its parents (for sorting easily. Your example seems to assume the same thing)

You could add the root_parent (highest parent) for each comment in your table:

```
+------+---------+-------------+
| id   | parent  | root_parent |             Corresponding trees
+------+---------+-------------+
| 1    |    0    |      1      |         1         3          5
| 2    |    1    |      1      |        / \                  / 
| 3    |    0    |      3      |       /   \                /  
| 4    |    1    |      1      |      2     4              6 
| 5    |    0    |      5      |           / 
| 6    |    5    |      5      |          /
| 7    |    4    |      1      |         7
+------+---------+ ------------+
```

Now, you can get your ordering by calling

```
select * from table1 order by root_parent, id
```

Let me know if it worked

Comment: And you can have a look here for equivalent if you don't use oracle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200636/oracle-connect-by-clause-equivalent-in-sql-server

Comment: I think MySQL (which the question was about) doesn't support any kind of recursive queries. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631048/connect-by-prior-equivalent-for-mysql